# Is is possible to use GStreamer without a GLib main loop?

Tags: gstreamer, glib

I am trying to use GStreamer as a video backend for a softphone we are developing in house. Our softphone is not GLib based, has its own event loops. Is it possible to set up a gst pipeline and put into various states without having a GMainLoop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the video streams work independetly, so even a "main loop" like `sleep(10)` will do the job. However, GLib is needed to capture any events or error messages from the gst pipeline.